# Postgresql: Keep connection open or create when needed

Tags: postgresql, libpqxx

I have multiple C++ class representing my postgresql tables. Each class can perform request on the associated table :

```
class MyTable : Table<MyDataType> {
    public:
        MyTable();
        ~MyTable();

        int add(std::vector<MyDataType> list);
        int remove(std::vector<MyDataType> list);

    };
}
```

Is it acceptable to create a new connection for each method instead of handling only one connection per class ?
Something like :

```
int MyTable::add(std::vector<MyDataType> list)
{
    pqxx::connection c(PQ_CONNECTION_STRING);
    // Do some request
    c.disconnect()
}

int MyTable::remove(std::vector<MyDataType> list)
{
    pqxx::connection c(PQ_CONNECTION_STRING);
    // Do some request
    c.disconnect();
}
```

Is there any drawbacks beside the time of establishing the connection ? i didn't find in the doc any indication against that.

Should i rather open a connection in the constructor and close it in the destructor , even if that mean keeping a connection open for nothing  ?

Thanks

Comment: How many (simultaneous) connections are you exactly talking about?

Comment: I dont have a precise number but probably not more than 10

Comment: Keeping things short, you should not have a use for more than 1 connection per pair [thread,database] (most probably you have a single DB, so 1 connection/thread), that ideally, you want to avoid disconnecting too often. To be frank, I did not understand what you're trying to achieve with every query being surrounded by connect/disconnect (they would not count as simultaneous connections if they are disconnected); within a thread, with your code, there can be only 1 active connection/thread anyway

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear. in other words : is it better to keep a connection open for the life of an object (even if no request is made) or should i create connection as needed

Comment: What I am recommending is different: open 1 single connection (if your app is mono-threaded) and pass all your queries through it. If you are able to tell when the connection is not going to be used, then sure, close it and reopen it the next time it's needed (example: at the start of a long calculation). The database will not have too much trouble dealing with a few idle connections from different users.

Comment: On the general case, C++ classes would an abstraction of single records/groups of records from 1 table or several tables linked to each other by foreign keys. I don't think much people would create singleton classes to represent DB tables ... A consequence of that general case is that if you get used to putting DB connection in the class constructor and disconnection in the class destructor, you will end up with **lots** of idle connections: 1 per **instance** of your classes. Even if it would work in your particular case, try to avoid such non-standard style.